# How to catch an exception and continue without stopping

Tags: python, exception

I have the following code

```
import msgpack
def deserialize(data)
   return msgpack.loads(data)

for data in stream:
    print deserialize(data)
```

Now, the issue is that some data is (maybe) corrupted.. and I am seeing this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 0: invalid continuation byte

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. I want to catch this error and irrespective of this error continue
   for rest of data.

so, I tried

```
def deserialize(data)
   try:
        return msgpack.loads(data)
   except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
      logger.error(" error")
```

But,the code halts with the same error?

Comment: if your question is simply to *catch an exception and continue without stopping* just replace `except UnicodeDecodeError as e:` with `except Exception as e:`

Comment: are you saying that the exception UnicodeDecodeError is being raised despite the try/except? Is the exception being caught or not? (i.e. are you getting the log?). Try what @alexmcf suggests and `print e` along with the error

Comment: Your attempted code should work—it will log the string `" error"` rather than any useful information, and it will return `None`, both of which are a little weird, but neither of which sounds anything like any problem you're describing.

Comment: Meanwhile, for question 1, the reason you're getting this error is likely that the data are in some other character set that's not UTF-8, but `msgpack` defaults to UTF-8. For example, byte `0xcc` means `Ì` in Latin-1 and related character sets, but it's not valid at all in UTF-8 unless it follows a prefix byte. (And if that's your problem, there are most likely other cases that aren't raising errors, but are instead giving you mojibake.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [unicode_errors='ignore' option](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python/blob/master/test/test_pack.py#L62)

```
msgpack.loads(data, unicode_errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why am I getting this error?

There are a few possible reasons, but they all come down to the same thing: you have something which is not UTF-8, but you're trying to read it as if it were.

First, if you actually have raw binary data, not text, you can't decode it as text. (Before version 2.0 of the protocol, there was no such distinction, so if you're learning from a tutorial or sample code written for an older version, it will be misleading.) The packing side needs to explicitly pack it as binary data. If it's using the same `msgpack` library, it does so by using the `use_bin_type=True` argument. If it's using some other library, you'll have to read the docs for that other library.

Second, if you have text, but the packer is packing it as, say, Latin-1, you can't unpack it as UTF-8. For example, that byte `0xcc` means `Ì` in Latin-1 and related character sets, which is a perfectly valid character, but it's an error in UTF-8 unless it follows a prefix byte. (And really, you're lucky you got an error, rather than silently doing the wrong thing and spewing mojibake all over.) Again, if the packing side is using the same `msgpack` library, it's just a matter of passing `encoding='utf8'` on both sides. If it's using a different library, you'll have to look at the docs for that other library. (And if you can't change the other side, then you need to figure out what encoding it's using—which may be difficult, because it may depend on the library, or the platform, or even the user's specified locale or system default character set…)

---

> I want to catch this error and irrespective of this error continue for rest of data.

Well, that's probably *not* what you want to do… but if you do, your existing code should work fine. It's raising a `UnicodeDecodeError` inside an `except UnicodeDecodeError as e:`. If that isn't working, most likely your actual code doesn't look like what you've shown us here.

It's worth noting that you seem to be mixing tabs and spaces in your source code, which is going to cause a lot of problems—things that look like they're at the same indentation level to you as a human may look like they're at different indentation levels to the Python compiler, and vice-versa. I can't quite see how that could cause the exact code you posted to fail (except by raising an `IndentationError` at compile time, which doesn't sound like what you're describing), but it can easily cause problems like this in even slightly more complex code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just log `' error'`:

```
def deserialize(data)
    try:
        return msgpack.loads(data)
    except:
        logger.error(" error")
```

If you want to record the nature of the error:

```
def deserialize(data)
    try:
        return msgpack.loads(data)
    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
        # ... do something with e
```

If you want to avoid the error, this should decode and replace any errored values, [see here](http://blog.luminoso.com/2012/08/20/fix-unicode-mistakes-with-python/) for more elegant solutions / info on this error...

```
data.decode('utf-8', 'replace').encode('utf-8')
```